# Blackberry Runtime Android apps execution

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i'm trying to run my android app already Verifyed with the Blackberry Builder Eclipse plugin. And after eclipse tried the console output is:

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx/.Main }
ActivityManager: Error type 3
ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.Main} does not exist.
```

I could run this project 2 months ago, but now i can't and don't understand why? Please some help!

Comment: So which is the real problem, this one or the one on the other post?

Comment: i do many tries, currently i'm getting the other problem, but sometimes i get this.